# Location of the installed python packages using pip3 on Google colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, instapy

I am trying to build a instagram bot using instapy on google colab.
I have installed the package using the following command in colab:

```
!pip3 install instapy
```

The issue is that I need to change some files in this module (ik its not recommended). **But I cannot locate where in the google colab file system is this module installed.**

I have tried looking into the "home" directory which is empty, as well as "/usr/lib/pythonx.x" of all the installed python versions but not there.
Any help would be appreciated greatly.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the below code snippet in google colab for getting the directory where the packages are installed. Replace `package` in `inspect.getfile(package)` with the package you want to find the installation directory for. The package is located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/instapy`

```
import os
import inspect
import instapy

package_path = os.path.dirname(inspect.getfile(instapy))
print(package_path)
```